# Cannot get location if using GPS only

Tags: gps, location-services

I have just factory reset my phone.
To get the location, there are 3 options:
High accuracy, Battery saving, GPS only.
For any app that would use/show my location, I get no location if using GPS only, even if I wait for several minutes with the phone in the backyard.
I do not recall checking this since a long time ago, but with my old phones (ca. 2010), which I think used pure GPS with no assistance, location worked wel..

Is this behaviour expected?

Can GPS location be underperforming for some reason?

Comment: In a different context, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silentlexx.gpslock) was recommended to help get the initial fix of satellites. See if that helps you. I haven't needed to try that